# How to prove that $n^{1.1} \not\in O(n(\log n)^2)$

Tags: asymptotics

This is a problem from a university exam:

> True or false: $n^{1.1} \in O(n(\log n)^2)$.

The solution says False, but I'm unable to prove it. I tried using the limit test for Big-O:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{T(n)}{f(n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{1.1}}{n(\log n)^2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{0.1}}{(\log n)^2}$

EDIT: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%28n%5E0.1%2F%28log%20n%29%5E2%2C%20n%2C%20inf%29) says that this limit is $\infty$, which is not a constant as the limit test requires. But I still don't know how to compute this limit by hand.

Comment: And what did you find for the last limit?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to proceed for that limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More basic looking, by L'Hopital
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow  \infty} \frac{x}{\log x} = \infty   $$

Next
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow  \infty} \frac{x}{(\log x)^2 } =\lim_{x \rightarrow  \infty} \frac{x}{2 \log x } = \infty   $$

The general induction step is
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow  \infty} \frac{x}{(\log x)^k } =\lim_{x \rightarrow  \infty} \frac{x}{k (\log x)^{k-1} } = \infty   $$

For non-integer exponents comparison may be used. Anyway, your
$$  \left( \frac{n^{0.1}}{(\log n)^2}  \right)^{10} = \frac{n}{(\log n)^{20}} $$
and both go to infinity.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{k}{\log k}\to\infty\implies\frac{n^{0.1}}{(\log n)^2}=\frac1{400}\cdot\left(\frac{n^{0.0.5}}{\log(n^{0.05})}\right)^2\to\infty$$